# Entering a Variable that Carries into Multiple Fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new to Excel so bear with me. :)

I have a multi-sheet workbook and I'm trying to automate certain tedious processes. For this question, the particular instance is this: I am manually entering data into Sheet 1... and certain rows will need to be input into Sheet 2 as well. Rather than entering everything twice, I was hoping to input the data into Sheet 1 and use references in Sheet 2 to pull it where it needs to be. No issues there whatsoever.

So, I have a row that looks like

```
='Sheet1'!C2
='Sheet1'!F2
='Sheet1'!W2
='Sheet1'!Z2
```

However, when I start a new row, I find myself having to manually do each field to update the row number and because the columns are not sequential (so I can't just do one and drag it over). I'm thinking that there has to be an easier way to do this.

[This is a graphical representation of what I'd like to accomplish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh1OT.png)

I just need some way to define a number in each row that will be automatically input into the reference functions in that row; a variable that carries into multiple fields.

It seems so simple in my head... manually set the first cell in a row equal to a value and write the reference functions so that the row value (y) ( ='NAME of'!Ay) is whatever is in the function's row's first cell --- does this make sense?

I hope this is possible! I appreciate any assistance that can be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your Row numbers are in column "C".

Use the following formula for:

Name-

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&C4)
```

ID-

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!Q"&C4)
```

Validation code-

```
 =INDIRECT("Sheet1!X"&C4)
```

Then you can drag this formula.

[image]

Comment: Very simple and extremely effective! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to throw together a simple example ...

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Sheet2 in formula view:

[image]

You should be able to add a row and drag down as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a table on the first sheet.

1. Select all the data that you want to carry over in the first sheet (including headers).
2. Go to the 'Insert' tab and select 'Table' (or press 'CTRL+T').
3. A dialogue box will pop up; make sure you check the box that says "My table has headers."
4. Click anywhere inside your new table and you'll notice that a new ribbon appears on the top that says 'Table Tools' and directly under that it should say 'DESIGN.' Select that tab, look to the far left and rename the table to something that makes sense. It should be named "Table1" or equivalent by default.
5. Now, let's assume you name the table 'Data' and you have a header called 'Name.' Simply go to another sheet and type '=Data[Name]'. You can drag this formula as far down as you need to go and it will automatically populate with the information in the original table.
6. Repeat step 5 with any other columns you wish to include.
7. Create a second table with the new data, name it something that makes sense.

Pros:

- There is no reference to any direct cell, so you can move the table or start the formula anywhere and you shouldn't have any problems.
- Your data is in a table that can be sorted by any of the columns of data within that table which can be incredibly useful.
- Any data you add to the original table by inserting a new row will propagate to any dependent tables.

Cons:

- You may experience issues if you add data to the bottom of the original table. Always insert a new row somewhere in the middle and re-sort the Name column alphabetically for best results.
- If any of the dependent lists end up too large, you'll see cells with a '#VALUE!' in them. Making the dependent lists into tables should solve this problem, but you can easily fix this by deleting any extra rows if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it!